# loop automático do comando copy

Tags: delphi-7

Se copio cada caractere individualmente do edit e dando uma quebra de linha com #13#10, uso um código como esse, só que dependendo do programa fica muito cheio de variveis

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a,b,c,d,e:string;

begin

a:=copy(Edit1.Text,1,1)+ #13#10;
b:=copy(Edit1.Text,2,1)+ #13#10;
c:=copy(Edit1.Text,3,1)+ #13#10;
d:=copy(Edit1.Text,4,1)+ #13#10;
e:=copy(Edit1.Text,5,1)+ #13#10;

memo1.Lines.Add(concat (a + B + C + d +e ));

end;
```

Não teria um jeito mais simples de se fazer mesmo enxugando o código acima usando um laço for, while ou de outra maneira, para usar apenas uma variável?

tipo assim:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a:string;
i:integer ;
begin

for i:=0 to Length(Edit1.text) do
a:=(copy(Edit1.Text,i,1)+ #13#10);

memo1.Lines.Add(a);

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Como não sabemos o tamanho do texto de entrada, então teremos que fazer um [Array Dinâmico](https://www.devmedia.com.br/arrays-dinamicos-no-delphi/26960), e percorrer cada caractere e adicionar o <kbd>Enter</kbd> no final.

```
program teste;
var 
  vetor :Array of String;
  n,i : integer;
  texto : string;
begin
 texto := 'StackOverflow';
 n := length(texto); 

 SetLength(vetor,n); // seta o valor máximo do array. 

 for i:=1 to high(vetor) do
 begin
   vetor[i] := copy(texto,i,1)+ #13#10;
 end;

 //Array para impressão
 for i:=1 to high(vetor) do
 begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(a);
    // write(vetor[i]);
    // Showmessage(vetor[i]);
 end

end.
```

Comment: Agradeçido David , mas é que estou com problema precisaria fazer o loop com Copy mesmo, mais ou menos naquele estilo que fiz acima com o for, com wile, se tiver condições  porque o programa já tá quase pronto,e é muita coisa que teria de mexer ali, dá mais 100 páginas de código, a maioria eu sei a quantidade de strings, então estou apenas presisando enxugar o código,  agradeçido novamente pela ajuda, se você tiver alguma outra dica fico agradeçido

Comment: @acs, tenta ler o código que postei de exemplo, a aplicar ao seu, não tem grandes mudanças, basicamente um vetor novo. Se não conseguir me fala que eu aplico a solução ao seu contexto.

Comment: Saudações David, realmente,  ficou muito bacana mesmo, obrigado

Comment: Poderia marcar a pergunta como respondida? Na dúvida, visite o [tour] para saber como fazer isso. Obrigado.

Comment: de nada, sim sem problema, já está respondido,  só  não encontrei o modo no link do tour acima que você passou, assim que achar eu marco ele, abraço